# "How to create a counter for a dictionary"

Tags: python, python-3.x

dic_1= {"1234567890":"1", this is the first card number so we give it number 1
        "1234567891":"2", this is the second card number so we give it number 2
        "1234567880":"3", this is the second card number so we give it number 3
    "1234567881":"4",
    "1234567890":"1", We already gave a number for this one so we dont          assign
a new number for this one, we keep the number we gave earlier

what i"m am trying to do is

1. Create a counter that starts at 1
2. Loop over each submission, and for each of those, loop over the card number
   If the card number is in the dict already, do nothing
3. If it is not, insert it and set the value equal to the counter as a string, increment the counter
4. At the end of this, I should have a mapping from card number to number
5. Loop over each submission, and for each of those, loop over the card number and replace the card number value with the value associated with that key in the dict you built above

Comment: i have a dictionary like this where the key is lets say card number.

dic_1= {"1234567890":"1", this is the first card number so we give it number 1
        "1234567891":"2", this is the second card number so we give it number 2
        "1234567880":"3", this is the second card number so we give it number 3
 "1234567881":"4",
 "1234567890":"1", We alreeady ggave a number for this one so we dont    assign
a new number for this one, we keep the number we gave earlier

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? It sounds like one.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show what you've tried and describe exactly how it's failing.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order the cards were inserted, then I think the easiest solution would look something like:

```
card_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b"]
dic1 = {card:num for card,num in enumerate(set(card_list))}
```

Outputs:

```
{0: 'e', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'c', 4: 'd'}
```

You are building a dictionary from the list of values in a set (which removes duplicates) and the enumeration will start counting from `0` to `len(card_list)-1`.

--

If the order matters to you then you can do something like this instead:

```
card_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b"]

dic1 = {}

counter = 1
for card in card_list:
    if not card in dic1:
        dic1[card] = counter
        counter += 1
```

Outputs:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Comment: but the card should look into the dictionary if the card number already exists or if we have already assigned a number for that card, if the card number exists then we do nothing.

Comment: The same thought applies. You are either going to have to keep a variable that works as a counter or you are going to have to do something like `count = max(dict1.values)+1` everything single time you add something to the dictionary.

Comment: lets put it this way, lets say i get submission of few card numbers, and in the file there are submission with same card number as well. now we want to hide the card number, so we want to create a dictionary where the first card number will be numbered as 1, second card number will be numbered as 2 and so on. also we have to look for submission with duplicate card number, if any submission has duplicate card number then we should skip over it and move on to next card number. so At the end of this, I should have a mapping from card number to number

Comment: in the dictionary the keys would be the card number and the value would be number of that card numbers, stored as a string, e.g., “1”